# O que significa executar lint no código?

Tags: compilação, eslint

Vi essa expressão *"lint code"* em alguns lugares, na IDE do *Visual Studio* e também ao executar o **NG CLI**, o cliente do Angular.

O que isso significa?
O que exatamente "*lint code*" faz?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Um **linter** ou **lint** é uma ferramenta para **análise estática de código**.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lint_(software)

> Um **linter** ou **lint** se refere a ferramentas que analisam código-fonte para acusar erros de programação, bugs, erros estilísticos, e construções suspeitas. O termo se origina de um utilitário Unix que examinava código-fonte em linguagem C. (...) O termo *lint* é derivado do nome de artefatos indesejáveis (fibra e penugem) na lã das ovelhas.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_program_analysis

> **Análise estática de programas** é a análise de software de computador que é efetuada sem realmente executar programas, em contraste com análise dinâmica, que é a análise efetuada em programas enquanto eles estão executando. Na maior parte dos casos a análise é feita em alguma versão do código-fonte, e em outros casos, em alguma forma do código-objeto.

Análise estática é o processo semelhante ao que o compilador faz, mas com o objetivo de produzir uma lista de erros, advertências (*warnings*) e pontos de melhoria no seu código.

A análise do código pode ser mais abrangente do que a que o compilador faz, porém devido à falta de referências cruzadas entre as unidades de código (i.e. entre os arquivos-fonte) ela pode perder contexto e não ser perfeita.

> Embora os compiladores modernos tenham evoluído para incluir muito das funções históricas de um lint, ferramentas do tipo do lint também evoluíram para detectar uma variedade ainda maior de construções suspeitas. Entre elas estão *"advertências sobre erros de sintaxe, usos de variáveis não-declaradas, chamadas de funções obsoletas, convenções de espaçamento e formatação, mau uso de escopo, queda automática para o próximo case em comandos switch, ausência de cabeçalhos de licença, [e] ...funcionalidades perigosas da linguagem"*.

[Fonte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lint_(software)#Overview)

#### Exemplos de erros, *warnings*, etc. (tirados do [manual](https://www.thinkage.ca/gcos/expl/lint/manu/manu.html#MessageClasses) de um linter):

**Error**

Os mesmos erros produzidos por um compilador: sintaxe inválida, esperado um `}` e encontrado um `:`, etc.

**Warning**

O padrão ANSI não permite atribuições entre ponteiros de tipos diferentes, mas a maioria dos compiladores ainda pode gerar código-objeto razoável para tal operação.

**Unusual**

```
i=i; // Válido, porém suspeito.
```

**Note**

```
printf("%ld",1); // Inválido, uma vez que %ld requer um long e está
                 // recebendo um int, porém sempre funciona em
                 // máquinas em que ambos têm o mesmo comprimento.
```

**MachDepd**

Sinaliza uma construção dependente da máquina em questão. Por exemplo, o resultado de `(-7/2)` pelo padrão ANSI pode ser truncado para cima ou para baixo dependendo da máquina.

Comment: interessante, a vida toda pensei em erros de compilação, não conhecia com esse termo

Answer (score 4):

Um linter é meio que um formatador de código com um pouco de análise sintática junto.

Eu conheço dois "linters" por assim dizer, o [HTMLHint](https://htmlhint.io/) usado para verificar código HTML de forma a sobrepor um pouco as regras da W3Schools, tem o TSLint, usado em Angular para organizar o código.

Algumas regras do TSLint incluem a necessidade ou não da presença de um `;` a cada comando, ou a necessidade de colocar o atributo `radix` ao fazer um parseInt. Pode-se controlar o linter durante o código Angular com uso de comentários, como `// tslint-disable-nextline:radix semicolon` antes da linha de código própriamente dita.

Comment: então quer dizer que ele configurável? lembrei, no *Visual Studio* é ESLint

Comment: Sim. o HTMLHint e o TSLint são configuráveis. No link do HTMLHint você pode colocar um código HTML e alterar as regras de forma a se adequarem ao que você quer, e então baixar o arquivo `.htmlhint` da própria página. O TSLint é configurado no arquivo `tslint.json` dentro da raiz de um projeto Angular.

Answer (score 1):

Sei que a pergunta é antiga e já foi respondida, mas gostaria de adicionar informação para quem possa encontrar esse tópico.

Outras linguagens de programação também possuem seus linters. No Python, há alguns e cito como exemplo o PyLint e o Flake8.

Os linters, como explicado nas respostas do @Piovezan e do @mutlei, acabam por analisar o código, seja verificando erro de sintaxe ou boas práticas.

O Flake8 dá um warning se a linha de código ultrapassar os 79 caracteres. O Flake8 também dá um warning quando a distância entre os imports e o ínicio do código da classe não é de duas linhas. Em ambos os casos, o código funciona normalmente se não seguir o que o linter pede, porque o problema é de boa prática e não de sintaxe.

Em resumo, os linters servem para que o programador digite um código correto, sem os erros de sintaxe e seguindo uma boa prática de programação relacionada a linguagem. Existem boas práticas que servem para todas as linguagens e há boas práticas mais específicas da linguagem e o linter irá ajudar a seguir um padrão.