# O que são falsos-positivos em programação?

Tags: terminologia

Vez em quando vejo este termo relacionado à programação e, afim de compreendê-lo melhor, fui pesquisar no Google mas só encontrei assuntos relacionados à área da saúde e a antivírus de computador.

Na programação tenho uma noção muito superficial sobre o assunto, que seria onde um código retorna um resultado X (quando deveria retornar Y) fazendo o programador achar que o código está funcionando como esperado ou como ele *acha* que deveria.

O exemplo abaixo seria um caso de falso positivo, ou apenas inexperiência?

```js
$("button").click(function(){
   var usuario = $("input").val();
   if(usuario){
      console.log("Usuário válido");
   }else{
      console.log("Usuário não pode ser vazio");
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Digite um nome de usuário e clique OK:
<br>
<input name="usuario">
<br>
<button>OK</button>
```

> No caso acima, não é permitido um nome de usuário vazio, mas se for
>   digitado apenas <kbd>SPACE</kbd> (espaços) o nome é aceito como
>   válido, porque o espaço também é um caractere como qualquer outro. Mas
>   acredito que nenhum programador deseja um nome de usuário "invisível"
>   apenas com espaços.

Enfim, qual seria a definição técnica de *falso-positivo* no âmbito da programação e quais as suas principais causas?

Comment: Uma condição qualquer que foi erroneamente avaliada e, que por conta disso, emitiu um alerta indevido.

Comment: Nunca ouvi o termo ser usado em programação, para além de software de antivírus ou na medicina. Para mim um falso posítivo é obter um resultado falso, errado, não preciso. Uma máquina em teoria nunca dará um falso positivo do seu código, o que por vezes acontece é bugs e mal implementações de frameworks. Por exemplo PHP em diversas versões continha porções de código que gerava resultados "inesperados". Isso sim poderia ser um candidato a falso positivo. Já o seu exemplo a meu ver seria falta de conhecimento do funcionamento da linguagem javascript.

Comment: No exemplo do nome em branco que você usou é um falso negativo.

Comment: Eu costumo usar "falso positivo" informalmente (e sabendo que talvez eu não esteja sendo tecnicamente correto) em situações nas quais uma condição inválida (seja um username que não deveria ser aceito, ou qualquer outro dado que não deveria passar) é considerada válida. Mas no fundo, é tudo erro, seja de programação (lógica errada), ou de requisito (alguém não pensou em todos os casos).

Comment: Usa-se o termo em [análise estática de código](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/330821/357). Para identificarem erros/warnings, os linters dependem de contexto fornecido pelos arquivos de código-fonte percorridos por eles. Quando esse contexto é incompleto eles podem concluir erroneamente que existe um erro/warning onde na verdade não existe nenhum. Esses são chamados de falsos-positivos.

Comment: Pode se aplicar a Data Mining por exemplo , um modelo é gerado , digamos prevendo se um cliente vai ficar inadimplente , haverá casos que o modelo vai prever a falta do pagamento e o cliente paga (falso negativo) e o contrário prevê o pagamento e o cliente não paga (falso positivo) , se a taxa for muito alta o modelo é pouco aderente à realidade. Não custa lembrar que como nada é 100% certo é aceitável em geral estas taxas em determinados níveis.

Comment: Esses dias recebi [essa imagem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xYVpX.jpg) que, digamos, "explica de forma didática" :-)

Answer (score 12):

Na verdade, até onde eu sei, não tem uma definição específica para o termo na computação, o termo é usado na ciência mesmo, e nós não deixamos de fazer algum tipo de ciência. Provavelmente não inventando coisas novas, mas aplicando a ciência já inventada, o que chamamos mais de engenharia.

Por não ser especialista em ciência e não ter domínio do uso do termo não sei se o exemplo citado possa caracterizar-se como falso positivo, pra mim é erro mesmo, mas não vou garantir. Acho que é erro porque o requisito é determinar invalidade do dado se não conter alguma informação útil, ter um espaço é uma informação inútil na maioria dos casos e parece ser inútil neste caso. Então ou é um requisito mal tomado ou é uma implementação que não considera o requisito corretamente.

Falso positivo é uma característica da estatística, em específico a parte que trata de inferências. Ele ocorre quando é possível a detecção equivocada de um problema. Se você declara o falso positivo como errado então ele passa ser erro. O mesmo vale para o falso negativo. Ele só continua sendo um falso resultado quando ele é uma posição aceitável em algum nível de análise. Me parece não ser possível usar o termo se não estamos fazendo uma [inferência estatística](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_inference).

No [SOen há uma pergunta sobre o assunto](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35357135/221800) com um contexto e este parece válido para o termo. Lá é possível um *warning* do compilador estar equivocado. E por isso mesmo ele é um *warning* e não um erro. Geralmente aquilo não é desejável, mas é aceitável, então o compilador faz o melhor dele para te dar uma informação correta, mas é sabido que ele não pode acertar sempre, então emite um alerta com probabilidade de estar errada.

O mesmo ocorre com detecção de *spam* e inúmeros outros domínios que depende de estatística, incluindo aí toda inteligência artificial. Portanto usamos isto mais em domínios de terceiros que estamos trabalhando do que no nosso domínio, a não ser que estejamos fazendo algo para o nosso domínio, que é o caso de [compilador](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/104814/101).

Geralmente adotamos essa possibilidade quando ter um falso positivo gera mais benefício do que ter zero informação confiável. A alternativa para eliminar o falso positivo seja considerar tudo negativo. Quando trabalhamos com estatística e não matemática precisa tudo pode ser falso negativo ou falso positivo, pode até ser preciso, e alguns problemas é possível dizer se é preciso ou não.

Tem uma estrutura de dados usada em índices chamada [Bloom filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter) que você pode garantir se uma chave não está em uma base dados, mas não pode garantir que está. Tem algo em torno de, sei lá, 95% a 99.9% de chance de estar certo, aí nos casos que ele não pode garantir você tem que fazer uma outra busca com outro método menos eficiente. Como a maioria dos casos ele acerta e garante isso, o ganho pode ser enorme já que poucas buscas obrigam o segundo algoritmo. E ocupa bem pouco espaço.

Por tudo isso eu chamo o problema citado de falha no desenvolvimento de software. Com mais informações eu poderia ser mais específico e quem sabe chamar de erro de programação.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).