# O que é type juggling?

Tags: php, terminologia, característica-linguagem, tipagem

O que é *type juggling*? Este conceito é relacionado somente com linguagens de tipagem dinâmica como o PHP e o JavaScript?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Só conheço o termo sendo usado em PHP. [Tem na documentação](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php). O termo provavelmente não poderia ser mais acertado, mas no mal sentido. E a definição ali é mal feita (é PHP, então é normal).

A documentação começa definindo algo que é típico de linguagem dinâmica, e até aí não sei se o termo cabe. Esse início indica que a variável tem o tipo do valor naquele momento. Segundo a [teoria dos tipos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_theory) isso nem é verdade. A variável não tem tipo, ou tem um tipo único com uma *tag* para um tipo do valor. Quem tem o tipo é só o valor.

Depois a documentação começa falar de coerção e aí o termo parece mais adequado. A linguagem faz um **malabarismo** para tentar interpretar o que o programador quer fazer e dar algum resultado, mesmo que não seja o que o programador quer fazer. Ele dá um resultado possivelmente errado para não dar erro. Parece ser um caso de inferir algo sem ter certeza, o que pode gerar um [falso positivo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/351665/101) e causar mais mal do que o bem que se esperava deste recurso da linguagem.

Não é "lindo" uma linguagem que você soma um booleano com uma *string* e o resultado é um inteiro?

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/xSdZJq). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/swjioiei-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Syntax/TypeJuggling.php).

Pelo menos agora dá um *warning*.

A coerção limitada que produz um resultado correto sempre não é problema. O *juggling* é fazer o que pode não dar certo.

Isto é típico de linguagem de *script* e faz sentido em códigos muito simples. Me desculpe se isso desagrada alguns, mas usar uma linguagem de *script* para fazer aplicações *enterprise* é simplesmente usar a linguagem errada, e o fato da linguagem começar colocar recursos de linguagem *enterprise* sem consertar esses problemas mostra que ela está perdida ou está tentando se salvar em um ambiente que o grosso dos códigos são *enterprise* e não *scripts*.

Isto é típico de linguagens de [tipagem fraca](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21508/101) e não de tipagem dinâmica, um termo que as pessoas confundem bastante.

De fato JS faz algo parecido, mas não vi o termo sendo usado nela. Existem outras linguagens de tipagem fraca que não usam o termo, até porque em muitos casos são um pouco mais controladas, por exemplo C.

Comment: "Não é "lindo" uma linguagem que você soma um booleano com uma string e o resultado é um inteiro?" Não consegui conter uma gargalhada, haha :D

Comment: Me lembrou dessa pérola aqui: https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat :D

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly tem muito essas coisas, tem uma cara aqui no Brasil q faz um standup de JS, é sensacional! Não achei online pra *linkar*, mas tem.

Comment: Vendo o resto, um dos dois copiou do outro, ou copiaram todos de outra pessoa.

Comment: O cara que faz esse standup no Brasil é o Rodrigo Cardoso @pokemaobr. A parte de JS evidentemente foi inspirada em uma talk como essa, mas ele tem atualizado e incluído chacotas a outras linguagens e frameworks. :D

Comment: @ErickPetrucelli é meu amigo :)