# O que é e para que serve um Bloom Filter?

Tags: algoritmo, estrutura-de-dados

Estava lendo [uma resposta aqui no SOpt](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/351676/101) (sim, é jocoso) e vi sobre Bloom Filter, queria mais informações sobre ele. Além do que é e para que serve, onde posso usar na prática?

Comment: Já leste esse https://www.ic.unicamp.br/~francesquini/mc202/files/aula26.pdf

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo sim.

Comment: eu tinha imaginado que sim :-)

Comment: até eu fiquei na curiosidade e fui procurar a respeito. o link https://www.psafe.com/blog/o-que-e-bloom-filter/ parece tirar 99% das duvidas sobre bloom filter de forma bem didatica. da uma olhada la

Comment: pois é cara, eu fui em busca do assunto também. Inicialmente não faz sentido nenhum ter uma estrutura que usa um hash probabilístico impreciso e com perda de desempenho no aumento do hash. Só fazendo o estudo assintético para ver se gera benefício em hashes pequenos. Ou isto, ou auxilia aplicações específicas que precisam eliminar os falsos negativos a qualquer custo. É de se pensar.

Comment: è uma filtragem de dados por eliminação onde a prioridade é descartar negativos

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bloom filter é uma estrutura de dados criada em 1970 por Burton Howard Bloom (daí o nome bloom filter)

Ele é uma estrutura probabilística com as seguintes propriedades:

- Possui eficiência de espaço
- Permite falsos-positivos
- Não permite falsos-negativos
- Elementos podem ser adicionados ao filtro
- Uma vez adicionados no filtro, elementos não podem ser removidos
- Quanto mais itens dentro do filtro, maior a chance de haver falsos-positivos
- São baseados em:

  - Funções de hash
  - Bit fields
- Para um bom funcionamento são essenciais:

  - Diversas funções de hash
  - Espalhamento uniforme

**Exemplo de aplicação pratica:**

O seu browser verifica todos os endereços que você acessa
para determinar se é um endereço seguro e poder te dar
um aviso caso não seja.

- Há bilhões de endereços na Internet.
- Podemos supor com uma boa margem de segurança que
  dentre eles há alguns milhões de sites fraudulentos.
- Seria ineficiente fazer com que todos os computadores do
  mundo fizessem download de uma lista completa de sites
  fraudulentos.
- Também não seria muito eficiente checar um banco de
  dados central a cada endereço que fosse acessado.
- O browser faz download de um filtro de Bloom contendo
  todos os sites reconhecidos como inseguros
- A cada endereço acessado, o browser verifica se ele está
  contido no filtro.
- Se a consulta ao filtro indicar que o endereço não está
  contido, então com certeza o endereço não está na lista
  de sites inseguros e o acesso continua normalmente.
- Se o filtro indicar que está contido, então pode ser que site
  esteja na lista de endereços inseguros. Neste caso o seu
  browser faz uma consulta adicional a um banco de dados
  na Internet (esta sim com a lista completa)
- Note que caso seja um falso positivo, a única
  consequência é uma demora um pouco maior para
  acessar o site desejado.

**Outras aplicações:**

- Verificação preliminar de direitos de acesso
- Evitar recomendar artigos/páginas que o usuário não
  gostou ou já leu
- Evitar leituras no disco em bancos de dados
- Verificar senhas fracas
- Corretores ortográficos
- Dentre outros

Fonte: [https://www.ic.unicamp.br/~francesquini/mc202/files/aula26.pdf](https://www.ic.unicamp.br/%7Efrancesquini/mc202/files/aula26.pdf)

Comment: Diga-se de passagem que esse slide citado é muito ruim... o conteúdo pode até não ser, mas é complicado ler com aquela imagem de fundo e esquema de cores. Tirando isso achei interessante o assunto... Muito boa resposta.